# Add combobox in to excel using jxl library

Tags: java, servlets, jxl

I am working on dynamic web project.
As per requirement, I want to prepare an excel file that contains a combobox.
I am familiar with jxl library.
I am work on servlet and jsp.

I am doing code in servlet. My code is as follows:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String floderPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        String lFilePath = "test1.xls";
        String filePathString = floderPath + File.separator + lFilePath;
        File lfile = new File(floderPath + File.separator + lFilePath);

      WorkbookSettings lbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
      WritableWorkbook lworkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(lfile, lbookSettings);

      WritableSheet lwriSheet = lworkbook.createSheet("Documents", 0);

      //Create lable
      Label lLblName = new Label(1, 2, "chintan");

      //create list
      ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
      arrList.add("DropDown1");
      arrList.add("DropDown2");
      arrList.add("DropDown3");

      //Create cobobox
      ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

      //create WritableCellFeatures for the combo option.
      WritableCellFeatures cellFeatures = new WritableCellFeatures();

      //bind list with WritableCellFeatures
      cellFeatures.setDataValidationList(arrList);

      //Now bind cobobox with WritableCellFeatures
      cellFeatures.setComboBox(cb);
      try {
        //Add lable in to excel  
        lwriSheet.addCell(lLblName);

        //Try to add code for add combobox into excel 
        /**
        Unable to found code for add combo into excel.
        */
    } catch (RowsExceededException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (WriteException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      lworkbook.write();
      try {
        lworkbook.close();
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Please guide me if any one knows.

Comment: What's a chobobox? Is it a box of chocolate covered hobos? Why would you want that in a spreadsheet??

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Fixed. Also, trolololol...

Comment: Combo-box means drop down list

Comment: Now I am able to add comboBox in excel using smart Excel lirary